# insert multidimensional array into mysqli db

Tags: image, insert, multidimensional-array, mysqli

I'm really hoping someone can help me out before I throw myself off a cliff. I have created a class to upload multiple images stored in a multidimensional array. The images are moved to a selected folder. I want to store the details of each image in a mysqli database. Each image should share a unique key which identifies it to a specific product.

The itm_pic_details (images) table has 5 fields
id auto increment id
itm_pic_id unique id linked to the product
itm_pic_dsc name of file
itm_file_date date added
itm_file_user (not needed to be filled in at this stage. Only for transaction purposes) 
itm_file_path (location of image)

I have included the 2 most important functions in my Upload class

```
    protected function processFile($filename,$error,$size, $type,$tmp_name,$overwrite){
$OK = $this->checkError($filename,$error);
if ($OK) {
$sizeOK = $this->checkSize($filename, $size);
    $typeOK = $this->checkType($filename, $type);
if ($sizeOK && $typeOK) {
$name = $this->checkName($filename, $overwrite);
$success = move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $this->_destination . $name);
if ($success) {
$message = "$filename uploaded successfully";
if ($this->_renamed) {
$message .= " and renamed $name";
}
$this->_messages[] = $message;
} else {
    $this->_messages[] = 'Could not upload ' . $filename;
}
  }
}
}


    public function move($overwrite = false) {
$field = current($this->_uploaded);
if(is_array($field['name'])){
foreach($field['name'] as $number => $filename){
//process the multiple upload
$this->_renamed = false;
$this->processFile($filename,$field['error'][$number],$field['size']    [$number],$field['type'][$number],$field['tmp_name'][$number], $overwrite); 
}
} else  {
    $this->processFile($field['name'],$field['error'],$field['size'],$field['type'],$field['tmp_name'],$overwrite);
}
```

}

Comment: serialize / unserialize?

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you are asking.

Comment: I don't think I understand the question. If you're wondering about mysqli, its used the same way like MySQL database, it is still the same mysql database, just controlled by different functions. ie. instead of mysql_query(), object is created from mysqli class and then $mysqli->query() is used.